# - in sql query causing syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, syntax-error

I am trying to update data from one database to another. They are on separate SQL servers but they are the same DB (live server and test server). My problem is it does not seem to like the - in my SQL server name and I don't know how to work around that. Here is the structure of the query and seemingly the only issue is where - is in repa-intranet.

```
update AdditionalInfo
set UserDefined25 = seredixserver.activem_repacorp_live.additionalinfo.userdefined25

from repa-intranet.activem_repacorp_live.additionalinfo 

join seredixserver.activem_repacorp_live.additionalinfo 
on repa-intranet.activem_repacorp_live.additionalinfo.ownerid = seredixserver.activem_repacorp_live.additionalinfo.ownerid
```

Comment: try throwing square brackets around the server name?  `[repa-intranet].activem_repacorp_live.....`

Answer (score 2):

Use explicit aliases and square braces:

```
update rai
    set UserDefined25 = sai.userdefined25
from [repa-intranet].activem_repacorp_live.additionalinfo rai join
     seredixserver.activem_repacorp_live.additionalinfo sai
     on rai.ownerid = sai.ownerid;
```

Square braces are not sufficient, because the `additionalinfo` in `update additionalinfo` is ambiguous.  Both tables have the same name.

Plus, aliases just make the query easier to read.

Comment: Good call on the alias usage.  Missed this with my initial comment on the main post, as I didn't even realize the two tables were named the same.

Answer (score 1):

Database names, table names and column names that contain characters like `-` need to be enclosed in rectangular brackets `[]`.

Please read this [article on Delimited Identifiers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for more information.